# Expanding circle with fixed outline width

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction, skshapenode

The effect I'm going for is like a raindrop on water, with the wave radiating out from the centre point.

I create a circle shape:

```
    let initialRadius = 4.0
    let myPath: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddArc(myPath, nil, 0, 0, initialRadius, 0, M_PI * 2, true)

    let myCircle = SKShapeNode()
    myCircle.path = myPath
    myCircle.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
    myCircle.lineWidth = 0.5
    myCircle.antialiased = false
    myCircle.fillColor = SKColor.orangeColor() // background is orange
    myCircle.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    myCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: myPath)
```

I then let the sprite expand, and fade out:

```
    let duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.7
    let fade = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(duration)
    let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(9.0, duration: duration)
    fade.timingMode = .EaseOut
    scale.timingMode = .EaseOut
    myCircle.runAction(fade)
    myCircle.runAction(scale)
```

This is close, but while the circle is correctly expanding in size, the lineWidth is also expanding. Can you think of a way to do this while keeping the line width constant?

Comment: add `myCircle.lineWidth = 0.5 / 9.0` to your scale action?

Comment: Interesting, @GradyPlayer. How would I scale the lineWidth (in a SKAction) without stepping on the SKAction.scaleTo?

Comment: I really don't know sprite kit, in core animation you can edit properties of views and then perform the animation, but sprite kit may be totally different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `customActionWithDuration` to re-draw the path with increasing radius (and constant line width), rather than use `scale`. Something like:

```
    // ... All as before, except...    
    // myCircle.runAction(scale)
    typealias ActionBlock = ((SKNode!, CGFloat) -> Void)
    let ab: ActionBlock = { (node, value) in
        if let drop = node as? SKShapeNode {
            let myPath: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
            CGPathAddArc(myPath, nil, 0, 0, initialRadius * (1.0 + value * 9.0 / duration) , 0, M_PI * 2, true)
            drop.path = myPath
        }
    }

    let newScale = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(duration, actionBlock: ab)
    myCircle.runAction(newScale)
```